# Why are my UITableViewCell's repeating?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uitableview

When I scroll offscreen I get some repeating cells. How can I fix this?

```
// Customize the appearance of table view cells.
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }

    switch (indexPath.row) {
        case 0:
            cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Bar Cafe",indexPath.row];
            break;
        case 1:
            cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Boutique Hester",indexPath.row];
            break;
        case 2:
            cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Boutique Hester Shoes",indexPath.row];
            break;
        case 3:
            cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Local Advice - Paulina",indexPath.row];
            break;
        case 4:
            cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Museum Brileyeglass",indexPath.row];
            break;
        case 5:
            cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Redlight Swans",indexPath.row];
            break;
        case 6:
            cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Reefer Flying Dutchman",indexPath.row];
            break;
        case 7:
            cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Reefer Tiani Hempshop",indexPath.row];
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }

    // Configure the cell...
    //cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Featured Event %d",indexPath.row];
    //cell.detailTextLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Description %d", indexPath.row];
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Does `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:` return 8? Also why pass `indexPath.row` to `stringWithFormat:` if it won't be used?

Comment: can u show us ur implementations of `-tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:` and `-numberOfSectionsInTableView:`

Comment: someone post the numberOfRowsInSection comment as an answer. That did the trick.

Comment: cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Boutique Hester",indexPath.row];   where you are using indexPath.row with stringWithFormat.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return 8;
}
```

this is the right implementaion of numberOfRowsInSection method if you return more than 8 then problem of repeating rows starts.

Comment: It wont solve the prb... Plz look the code correctly.. He is adding accesoryType at last line only.. so there will be atleast a empty value with accesory type

Comment: why there will be a empty cell with accessory all the data is static if you return number of rows 8 then only for 0 to 7 row it is called.

Answer (score -1):

Because in the cellForRowAtIndexPath method, the cells are reused and whenever the u scroll, the indexpath will start from 0. For more detail u can use NSLog(@"Index Path.row=%d",indexPath.row) and see in Console window.

Comment: This is not correct.  Cells are re-used but indexpaths do not restart from zero.

Answer (score -1):

Your code working fine for me, no problems at all.

I think you want to print indexPath.row at each row. If so, you have to change as follows:

```
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Reefer Tiani Hempshop %d",indexPath.row];
```

Even though the numberOfRowsInSection: returns more than 8 there will be no chance for reputation.

Comment: Actually, as soon as the cells are re-used there will be what appears to be repetition. Because when the cell is reused in a later row, the text will not be reset because only the first 8 cases are handled. The default in that case statement will do nothing, leaving the text from the last time that cell was used.

Comment: Your solution cant solve the problem actually problem is of repetetion not printing any thing and repetetion is because of number of rows.

Comment: @ishu: there is no chance for repetetion because of number of rows

Comment: @kingOfBliss:I check the code on simulator but i face that problem of repetetion thats why i give the solution which works for me.and your suggestion of printing indexPath.row is good but it is not according to problem.This may be comment not answer,answer must be related to problem.

Comment: @ishu: the code really works fine for me thts y i posted this ans

Comment: @ishu: if it returns more than 8 means then there will be blank cell with accessory button alone

Comment: @KingOfBliss When it calls more than times (not neccessary to 8 times)  actually when cell!=nil then cell is creating by reusable cell which having label and label having old data because he is not cleaning the data of label thats why cells are repeating.and because of accessory type only > this shows on cell thats it.

Comment: @kingOfBliss actually you check only for 9 rows or 10 which are fit in table without scrolling but when you scroll and number of rows are more than number of rows fit in table then problem of repeteion arises. And he returns more number of rows thats why problem is in numberOfRows method.